# TimesNewRoman font in Latex

Tags: fonts, times

I'm trying to use Times New Roman Font in Latex - MiKTeX 2.9 with command

```
\usepackage{times}
```

but it said

> pdfTex error (ptmr8z.vf): invalid character code

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: What about `\usepackage{math­ptmx}`?

Comment: Or `\usepackage{newtxtext}`. And, if you want math, you can use `\usepackage{newtxmath}` (and if you have them installed `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`).

Comment: Have a look at either the `tgtermes` or the `newtxtext` package.

Comment: The file `ptmr8z.vf` is from the old version of `cspsfonts` package (from CSTeX). This is TimesRoman font in IL2 encoding. The CSpsfonts package was generally upgraded at October 2012, see http://math.feld.cvut.cz/olsak/cstex-e.html , the middle of this page. The most probably reason of this problem is that there exist files from old and new versions of this package mixed in the computer. The files include internal links from `*.vf` to `*.tfm` to `r*.tfm` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Instead using `\usepackage{times}`, for using **Times** font you can do:

```
%preambula here
\begin{document}
\usefont{T2A}{ftm}{m}{sl}
    Times New Roman?
\end{document}
```

Hope, it'll be helpful!

Comment: it doesn't work for me : no such encoding as T2A.